# Embedding a Flash player

Tags: flash

How can somebody embed a Flash player in the FLV/SWF video itself? I have a certain requirement that I must have a standalone SWF/FLV with a built in Player (start, stop, pause, progress bar). As i have said, this must be done via a standalone file with no additional xml or player files which have to be kept with the original file. Any help on the matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like making projector. Options:

- Native one: [Flash Projector](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_projector.html)
- Adobe Air
- 3rd party alternative: [Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/)